# Rails - Sending XML or JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I'm new to Rails and trying to send a request to Chargify to cancel a subscription. Their API says I need to send the method DELETE to a xml URL. This isn't a Chargify based question but rather... how would I have a user click a button that then generates this request and sends it within my Rails app? You can view this url to see what I"m trying to do - http://docs.chargify.com/api-subscriptions#cancel. Also it's working fine when I run a command-line test so I know my code works, just now sure how to put it into my Rails app (view/controller). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work using Net::HTTP in the Ruby Standard Library:

```
require 'net/http'

http = Net::HTTP.new('subdomain.chargify.com')
request = Net::HTTP::Delete.new('/subscriptions/1337.xml')
response = http.request(request)
```

You could include it in your controller's method, but unless you need to make sure the request finished before you send a response back, I recommend making the request to Chargify in a background job.  Check out the [**delayed_job**](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job) or [**resque**](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the Net::HTTP library. Also, checkout the source of some other ruby API bindings on Github to see how they use and structure this type of behavior (specifically, Twilio, Dropbox, and Flickraw).